# Find a plane that will have no points of intersection with a line.

Tags: vector-spaces

Is there a simple way to do this?

I'm thinking that the plane must have to be somehow parallel to the line but I don't know how to calculate this.

Answer (score 2):

The scalar product of the normal vector of the plane and the direction vector of the line must be $0$.

In this case, to ensure that the line is not in the plane, it is enough to choose one point of the line and to show that it is not in the plane.

Comment: I am not sure whether "direction vector" is the proper name.

Comment: "direction vector" is indeed the proper name.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume the line is given in the form $
\ell: \vec{x}=\vec{a}+t\vec{b}$

Visually, it is very safe to conclude that if the normal of our plane, $\pi$, is $\vec{n}$, then it's perpendicular to $\vec{b}$- http://sketchtoy.com/67343930. Hence it must satisfy $ \vec{n} \cdot \vec{b}=0$

Another thing we must conclude that $\ell$ isn't contained in $\pi$. We can verify that by demanding $\vec{a}\notin \pi$
So take a random equation of $\pi$- $\vec{n}\cdot\vec{x}+d=0$. It must satisfy $\vec{n}\cdot\vec{a}+d \neq 0$